# Does Jasmin have an admin API?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, jasmin-sms

Does Jasmin SMS Gateway - apart from the JCLI Concolse - have a managent API for **Admin user actions** where I can create, modify, delete Bulk **bulk sms users**?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few attempts to implement a UI for `Jasmin`.
There's no known open-source package for this.

Try to reach `jasminsms` support for possible feedback on your questions.